# Call to clojure.core/fn did not conform to spec

Tags: clojure

I'm getting this message:

> Exception in thread "main" clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: Call to clojure.core/fn did not conform to spec:
> In: [0] val: (- (int p1__148#) 48) fails spec: :clojure.core.specs.alpha/arg-list at: [:args :bs :arity-1 :args] predicate: vector?
> In: [0 0] val: - fails spec: :clojure.core.specs.alpha/arg-list at: [:args :bs :arity-n :args] predicate: vector?
> #:clojure.spec.alpha{:problems ({:path [:args :bs :arity-1 :args], :pred clojure.core/vector?, :val (- (int p1__148#) 48), :via [:clojure.core.specs.alpha/args+body :clojure.core.specs.alpha/arg-list :clojure.core.specs.alpha/arg-list], :in [0]} {:path [:args :bs :arity-n :args], :pred clojure.core/vector?, :val -, :via [:clojure.core.specs.alpha/args+body :clojure.core.specs.alpha/args+body :clojure.core.specs.alpha/args+body :clojure.core.specs.alpha/arg-list :clojure.core.specs.alpha/arg-list], :in [0 0]}), :spec #object[clojure.spec.alpha$regex_spec_impl$reify__2436 0x58faa93b "clojure.spec.alpha$regex_spec_impl$reify__2436@58faa93b"], :value ((- (int p1__148#) 48) [x] (* x x)), :args ((- (int p1__148#) 48) [x] (* x x))}, compiling:(/Users/hassan/Desktop/fourclojure/src/fourclojure/120.clj:8:31)
> at clojure.lang.Compiler.checkSpecs(Compiler.java:6891)
> at clojure.lang.Compiler.macroexpand1(Compiler.java:6907)
> at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6989)
> at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6773)
> at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6991)
> at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6773)
> at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6729)
> at clojure.lang.Compiler$BodyExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:6100)
> at clojure.lang.Compiler$FnMethod.parse(Compiler.java:5460)
> at clojure.lang.Compiler$FnExpr.parse(Compiler.java:4022)
> at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:7001)
> at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6773)
> at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6729)
> at clojure.lang.Compiler$InvokeExpr.parse(Compiler.java:3881)
> at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:7005)
> at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6773)
> at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6729)
> at clojure.lang.Compiler$InvokeExpr.parse(Compiler.java:3881)
> at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:7005)
> at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6773)
> at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6991)
> at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6773)
> at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6729)
> at clojure.lang.Compiler$BodyExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:6100)
> at clojure.lang.Compiler$FnMethod.parse(Compiler.java:5460)
> at clojure.lang.Compiler$FnExpr.parse(Compiler.java:4022)
> at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:7001)
> at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6773)
> at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6991)
> at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6773)
> at clojure.lang.Compiler.access$300(Compiler.java:38)
> at clojure.lang.Compiler$DefExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:595)
> at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:7003)
> at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6773)
> at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6729)
> at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:7066)
> at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7514)
> at clojure.lang.Compiler.loadFile(Compiler.java:7452)
> at clojure.main$load_script.invokeStatic(main.clj:278)
> at clojure.main$script_opt.invokeStatic(main.clj:338)
> at clojure.main$script_opt.invoke(main.clj:333)
> at clojure.main$main.invokeStatic(main.clj:424)
> at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:387)
> at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
> at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:702)
> at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
> Caused by: clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: Call to clojure.core/fn did not conform to spec:
> In: [0] val: (- (int p1__148#) 48) fails spec: :clojure.core.specs.alpha/arg-list at: [:args :bs :arity-1 :args] predicate: vector?
> In: [0 0] val: - fails spec: :clojure.core.specs.alpha/arg-list at: [:args :bs :arity-n :args] predicate: vector?
> {:clojure.spec.alpha/problems ({:path [:args :bs :arity-1 :args], :pred clojure.core/vector?, :val (- (int p1__148#) 48), :via [:clojure.core.specs.alpha/args+body :clojure.core.specs.alpha/arg-list :clojure.core.specs.alpha/arg-list], :in [0]} {:path [:args :bs :arity-n :args], :pred clojure.core/vector?, :val -, :via [:clojure.core.specs.alpha/args+body :clojure.core.specs.alpha/args+body :clojure.core.specs.alpha/args+body :clojure.core.specs.alpha/arg-list :clojure.core.specs.alpha/arg-list], :in [0 0]}), :clojure.spec.alpha/spec #object[clojure.spec.alpha$regex_spec_impl$reify__2436 0x58faa93b "clojure.spec.alpha$regex_spec_impl$reify__2436@58faa93b"], :clojure.spec.alpha/value ((- (int p1__148#) 48) [x] (* x x)), :clojure.spec.alpha/args ((- (int p1__148#) 48) [x] (* x x))}
> at clojure.core$ex_info.invokeStatic(core.clj:4739)
> at clojure.core$ex_info.invoke(core.clj:4739)
> at clojure.spec.alpha$macroexpand_check.invokeStatic(alpha.clj:689)
> at clojure.spec.alpha$macroexpand_check.invoke(alpha.clj:681)
> at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:156)
> at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:144)
> at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:702)
> at clojure.lang.Compiler.checkSpecs(Compiler.java:6889)
> ... 45 more

When I run this code:

```clj
(defn count-less-than-square [l]
  (->>
   l
   (map (fn [n] (->> n
                     str
                     (map #(-> % int (- 48) (fn [x] (* x x)))) ; The problem is that fn
                     (reduce +)
                     (list n))))
   (filter #(< (first %) (second %)))
   count))
```

However, when I run it like this:

```clj
(defn pow [a b] (reduce * 1 (repeat b a)))

(defn count-less-than-square [l]
  (->>
   l
   (map (fn [n] (->> n
                     str
                     (map #(-> % int (- 48) (pow 2)))
                     (reduce +)
                     (list n))))
   (filter #(< (first %) (second %)))
   count))

(pp/pprint (count-less-than-square (range 30)))
```

It works fine.

Why is that `(fn [x] (* x x))` crashing? It works fine in the REPL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `->` macro you are using which inserts the threading value in the first position, right after the `fn` symbol.
So this:

```
(map #(-> % int
          (- 48)
          (fn [x] (* x x))))
```

becomes something like:

```
(map #(fn
        (- (int %) 48)
        [x]
        (* x x)))
```

That is obviously invalid because `fn` expects the first arg to be a vector of function parameters, which is what the error message is trying to say:

```
fails spec: :clojure.core.specs.alpha/arg-list at: [:args :bs :arity-1 :args] predicate: vector?
```